# GitHub git hook on remote site to update wiki pages

Tags: git, github, github-pages, githooks

The LTP project on GitHub stores wiki sources in [`doc/`](https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp/tree/master/doc) directory (but there are other files which aren't wiki sources).

From time to time I update the GitHub wiki with a local script, which

1. pulls [`ltp.wiki.git`](https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp.wiki.git)
2. copies files from ltp.git `doc/` directory into `ltp.wiki.git`
3. `git commit .` in `ltp.wiki.git`
4. `git push` in `ltp.wiki.git`

I'd like to have a git hook, which would do it after push on remote repository ([`post-update`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-update)?). Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub doesn't support Git hooks (on GitHub.com at least, they *are* supported on GitHub Enterprise). However, you can use [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) to run arbitrary code on a push, albeit in an isolated VM and not on the actual Git server.

In `.github/workflows/wiki-mirror.yml` (or whatever filename you want in `.github/actions`), you can add an Action to do the syncing. Since GitHub wikis expect markdown files, this changes the extensions of the `.txt` files to match:

```yaml
name: "Mirror doc/ to wiki"

# Run on changes to the `doc` directory on the `master` branch
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
    paths:
      - 'doc/**'

jobs:
  mirror:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout main
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          path: [repo name]
      - name: Checkout wiki
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          repository: "[owner]/[repo name].wiki"
          path: [repo name].wiki
      - name: Copy files
        run: |
          git config --global user.email "actions@github.com"
          git config --global user.name "Wiki mirror"
          cp $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/[repo name]/doc/*.txt $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/[repo name].wiki
          cd $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/[repo name].wiki
          rename.ul -v .txt .md *.txt
          git add .
          # only commit if there are changes
          git diff-index --quiet HEAD -- || git commit -m "sync from doc/"
          git push
```

Comment: FYI Debian/Ubuntu does not ship `rename` from util-linux: https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/amd64/util-linux/filelist. But that's just a detail (there are more changes needed - camel case, thus OK to use plain `cp`).